# Distance between x-axis ticks in core plot

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-plot

Am breaking my head on this since yesterday (tried various attribute settings, goggled, stackoverflow'ed , et al,... in vain). At last, I decided to post this! I hope am not asking anything dumb! Please pardon me if so! :)

**My Project Settings:**
Simple iPhone App that uses Core Plot, Xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0, 
Testing using iOS Simulator

**My Question** : I used the wonderful and DatePlot example from Core Plot site and am plotting (Scatter Plot) dates along the x-axis. am having two plots. It's all plotted fine (thanks to the simple example!);  But the distance between each plot (along the x-axis) i.e. the distance between the major ticks is too small ... it's like this :

[image]

(Notice that the two red-colored ellipse-plots are so close to each other...that's the current distance between the ticks)

**My Code Snippet (Relevant)**

// Set up the axes
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet           = (CPTXYAxisSet *) lineChart.axisSet;

```
CPTXYAxis *x                    = axisSet.xAxis;
NSTimeInterval oneDay   = 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0;
x.majorIntervalLength           = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
x.majorTickLength               = 1.0;
// Get a set of custom label for the X Axis
x.axisLabels                    = [self getXLabelSetForLineChart:x];
x.labelRotation                 = M_PI / 2;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter   = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateStyle          = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter  = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
timeFormatter.referenceDate      = today;
x.labelFormatter                 = timeFormatter;
x.labelingPolicy                 = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
```

Can someone please help!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `length` of the plot space `xRange` is too long. This compresses your data points into a smaller area and leaves unused spaces off to the right.

Comment: Thank you, Eric! Let me try it out. I think I have to set a more intelligent value to xRange, rather than some approximate value.

Comment: +1 . That worked, Eric! Thanks so much! :) Awesome work by you guys on Core Plot! Thank you! :)